# Auto `Zoom to Fit Screen` on open any xml layout in Android Studio

Tags: android, visual-studio

I'm use AS 2.3.3.

I want to have activated option `Zoom to Fit Screen (0)` on open any layout in xml (tab 'design').

Default, on open layout I see 100%. So, I needed each time click on zoom icon.

Also, I see that key `0` (zero number) binded to this action. It can be solution, but it do not work for me. Or I'm something wrong to do?

Can anybody help me?